# If $X + X^T$ is positive definite, is $X^{-1} + X^{-T}$ also positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true or is there a counterexample?

Comment: A weaker condition would be: the eigenvalues have real part $>0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X + X^T$ is positive definite iff for every nonzero vector $v$, 
$v^T (X + X^T) v = 2 v^T X v > 0$.  In particular, it implies $X$ is invertible.  Taking $w = X v$, this is equivalent to $w^T X^{-1} w > 0$ for all nonzero vectors $w$, and thus to $X^{-1} + (X^{-1})^T$ being positive definite.

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite
$$
X^{-1} + X^{-T} = X^{-T}(X+X^T)X^{-1}.
$$
Then for a vector $x\ne0$ it follows
$$
x^T(X^{-1} + X^{-T})x = x^TX^{-T}(X+X^T)X^{-1}x = (X^{-1}x)^T(X+X^T)(X^{-1}x)>0,
$$
as $X^{-1}x\ne0$ and $X+X^T$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\langle \,(X + X^{T}) v, v \rangle = \langle X v, v\rangle + \langle v, X v\rangle$$
For $w= X^{-1}w $ the above expression becomes
$$  \langle w, X^{-1} w\rangle + \langle X^{-1}w, w\rangle= \langle \,(X^{-1} + X^{-T}) w, w \rangle$$

Obs: Both conditions are stronger than the equivalent conditions $\sigma(X),\, \sigma(X^{-1}) \subset\{z\ | \  \mathcal{Re}z > 0 \}$